# Return basemap maximum value

Tags: python, numpy, math, matplotlib-basemap

This is quite a general question;

Is there a way to return the maximum value in a Basemap plot? I know for an array in numpy you can do it with amax etc, but when using basemap you might only be plotting a certain part of the array (etc data might be set for -90 to 90 lat, -180 to 180 long, but if I'm plotting a map over Europe then calculating the max of this array will give me the maximum value of the world, not in Europe which is being plotted.)

The basemap kwargs llcrnrlat,llcrnrlon,urcrnrlat,urcrnrlon, could probably be used in such a way to get the correct array coordinates, was just wondering if Basemap has a feature that does all this?

Etc if I have a plot generated below, the max is about 18. But the data I'm using to plot this is global data (an array of size 721x1440, extending -90 to 90, and -180 to 180), where the max value is likely to be larger than this and therefore of no use to this plot/the user.

Below is a very basic/simplified version, I can't post the data unfortunately..

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=60,lon_0=0,resolution='l')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 91., 10.), labels=[1,0,0,0], fontsize=12)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180., 181., 20.), labels=[0,0,0,1], fontsize=12)
plt.text(1,1,'@MetmanJames')

def Make_Grid(m):
    lat = np.linspace(90,-90,721)
    lon = np.linspace(-180,180,1440)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
    X, Y = m(X, Y)
    return X,Y

X,Y = Make_Grid(m)
SomeDataSet = np.array(721,1440) #Some data from a Grib file, can't upload this data unfortunately
cs = m.contourf(X,Y,SomeDataSet,extend='both')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting the maximum value in terms of:  1) Max Lat/Lon of your viewing window; 2) Max Lat/Lon of your data within viewing window (which would require further defining of "Max"); 3) Max Lat and Max Lon, independently; or 4) Max Lat/Lon in terms of distance from a given point?

Comment: The maximum value of the data in the viewing window, what the user can see (which is what basemap displays)

Comment: Okay, and how are you defining "maximum" here?  Closest to a given corner, distance from center?  Geospatial coordinates aren't like the number line, there's not a clear definition of "max"

Comment: I updated the question if this makes it any clearer. The maximum value of the data that is displayed in the window, in my example 18C.

Comment: I see--you're looking for the coords & value of the maximum temperature in the viewing window.  Thank you for the plot and example.  Can you edit your question to also provide a sample of your code and how your data is stored?  I can post an answer then for you if you have those details

Comment: Yeap precisely. I've added some very simplified code - not allowed to upload the data, but hopefully is of some use. Thanks v much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122118/discussion-between-dblclik-and-james-warner).